# How can I install a ruby gem that cannot be found?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm attempting to install [s3nuke](https://github.com/SFEley/s3nuke).  From an up to date Mac OS with up to date ruby and gems.

First I cloned the git repository to my `/var/src/` (now `/var/src/s3nuke`).

The install on the README is simple enough:

```
gem install s3nuke
```

Response:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 's3nuke' (>= 0) in any repository
```

Most help on this error assume I'm behind some proxy.  I'm not.  I can ping rubygems or rubyforge just fine.  I can update successfully and  even install other gems.  Here are some examples:

```
$ gem -v
1.8.24
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
$ gem install rubygems-update
Successfully installed rubygems-update-1.8.24
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rubygems-update-1.8.24...
Installing RDoc documentation for rubygems-update-1.8.24...
$ update_rubygems
RubyGems 1.8.24 installed
$ sudo gem update --system
Latest version currently installed. Aborting.
```

So let's try some other gems:

```
$ gem install eventmachine
Fetching: eventmachine-1.0.0.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed eventmachine-1.0.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for eventmachine-1.0.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for eventmachine-1.0.0...
$ gem install clamp
Fetching: clamp-0.5.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed clamp-0.5.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for clamp-0.5.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for clamp-0.5.0...
```

So I'm up to date, and can install other gems.  But s3nuke still won't budge.

```
$ gem install s3nuke
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 's3nuke' (>= 0) in any repository
```

I even added another gem source (http://gems.rubyforge.org/), but still no luck.

Can you help?

Here's my env:

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.a
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin12.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-12
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
     - /Users/my_username/.gem/ruby/1.8
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["http://rubygems.org/", "http://gems.rubyforge.org/"]
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
     - http://gems.rubyforge.org/
```

I'd try to install manually, but the [s3nuke git repository](https://github.com/SFEley/s3nuke) doesn't include a s3nuke.gem.

What do you recommend?

Comment: Why are you updating your system's version of Ruby? Don't mess with that. Instead, use rbenv or RVM to create a sandboxed version, which you can fiddle with all day long, and blow away if something goes wrong. Apple put Ruby on the machine for their purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you use bundler, you can add to your Gemfile next line:

```
gem "s3nuke", :git => "git://github.com/SFEley/s3nuke.git"
```

Or you can install with [specific_install gem](https://github.com/rdp/specific_install)

```
gem install specific_install
gem specific_install -l http://github.com/SFEley/s3nuke.git
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly add the following line to your Gemfile:

```
gem 's3nuke', :git => 'git://github.com/SFEley/s3nuke.git'
```

The gem will be installed the next time you do `bundle install` (assuming you're using Bundler)